# How do i send tappedItem object to next page?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page with a list view of news items fetched from an api. 
This listview only shows the title.
When one of the titles is tapped, it should navigate to a detailed page for the tapped news.

I have tried to send it in many different ways, but I can't make it work.

This is my latest try on using the object tapped on the newsDetail page.

(PAGE1 WITH ALL NEWS) itemTapped method ->

```
 public async void goToNews(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(eventArgs.ToString());
        newsITEM news = eventArgs.Item as newsITEM;

        if (news == null)
            return;

        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new newsItem(news));
    }
```

(DETAILED PAGE2 OF TAPPED NEWS) handler of this item

```
 public newsItem(newsITEM news)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var newsITEM = new newsITEM(Navigation, news);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newsITEM._news.title.rendered);
        BindingContext = newsITEM;
    }
```

I have a rootObject class, this is filled with all the news on page1.

And then I have a newsITEM class, this has the rootObject within, this am i trying to fill with tappedItem and then send to page2.

It behaves as the object is null.
Can someone lead me to the right solution? 
I know the question is a bit confusing, but i hope you will understand the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
    void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Item == null) {
            return;
        }

        var selectedItem = (Model) e.Item; // model
        Navigation.PushAsync(new newsITEM(selectedItem)); // pass the selected whole item from list to DetaiPage 'selectedItem' using constructor
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

    }
```

and in your detail page, it will returns all the tapped item data from its parent page;

```
public newItemPage(Model item) // get selected listview tap model object using this constructor(Model item)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "");

        Title = item.first_name;
        this.BindingContext = item; // binding using this 'item' model object and do whatever
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, when i do this it gives me the error "specified cast is not valid" @Prasanth

Comment: on this  "var selectedItem = (newsITEM)e.Item; "

Comment: Yes my model is newsITEM and newsItem is my page ;) know it's weired naming conventions but i'll change it after this works.

Comment: but it still don't work? :D

Comment: still what issues are you facing

Comment: newsITEM = model 
newsItem = page

Navigation.PushAsync(new newsItem(selectedItem)); is the right way to push to page but it, gives me the error: "specified cast is not valid" @Prasanth

Comment: Did you set a constructor on your detail page as using same Model 'newsITEM' as set like this public newsItem(newsITEM selecteditem)

Comment: yes it looks like this "public newsItem(newsITEM item) "

Comment: could it have something to do with my models?

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check on listview tapped event, check here 'var selectedItem = (newsITEM) e.Item;' here the selected items are return

Comment: are you binding the objects in listview using this model - newsITEM

Comment: no im using a model called rootObject. Should i use the same object?

Comment: because newsITEM has the same structure and values just with a prefix in names

Comment: "selectedItem" is null, "newsITEM" says "non public memebers", e.Item has all the right values

Comment: if you invoke any object from the event handler, use the same model which you used for binding the listview

Comment: it still says specified cast not valid if I change it to the same model as binded to listview

Comment: IT WORKS NOWWWWW!! ;) thank you man! just removed the paranthensies in front of e.Item and made a contructor in page2 and it works

Comment: @AndersBootsmannLarsen please accept my answer

Comment: can you please upvote my answer?

Answer (score 0):

use can send an item model to next class constructor.

```
private async void EventList_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item= e.Item as Model;
        if (item!= null)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new EventDetail(item));
        }
    }
```

And simple give the parameter of that model in next class as

```
 public EventDetail(Model item)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       //do whatever you want with model item

    }
```

Comment: says that "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Is your parent page a navigation page? If not, no stack is maintained for navigation and hence the navigation object is not defined. This code should work if your parent page is a navigation page.